# Create a full and complete binary tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

### Purpose:

I would like to create a **full and complete binary tree**, which saves a String value in its leaves, recursively.

**Example 1:**
Let's say you want to save two Strings in your tree. So you will need a root and two leaves.

```
   *  <- root node
  / \
v0   v1   <- leaves
```

**Example 2:**
Let's say you want to save three Strings in your tree. So you will need a root, two inner Nodes but four leaves, so the tree is still complete.

```
       *    <- root node
      / \
     +   +  <- inner node
    /     \
   /       \  
  / \     / \
v0   v1   v2 v3   <- leaves
```

---

### Math trickery:

Its fairly straightforward to calculate the specs for the binary tree.

**Height:** ⌈log2 expectedNumOfStrings⌉

```
double height = Math.log(expectedNumOfStrings) / Math.log(2);
int roundedHeight = (int) Math.ceil(height);
```

**Number of leaves**: 2<sup>Height</sup>

```
int numOfLeaves =  (int) Math.pow(2, roundedHeight);
```

**Number of inner Nodes:** 2<sup>h</sup> − 1

```
int numOfInnerNodes = (int) (Math.pow(2, roundedHeight)-1)
```

---

### Implementation:

Let's implement a couple of classes for this binary tree. We'll need a  `BinaryTree` class.

```
/**
* Create a complete binary tree recursively depending on the expected leaves.
*/
public class BinaryTree {

  private InnerNode root;
  private LeafNode current;


  public BinaryTree(int expectedNumOfStrings) {
    //sets root node
    this.root = new InnerNode();
    //set inner nodes
    root.createInnerNodes(expectedNumOfStrings);
    //set leaves
    root.createLeaves(expectedNumOfStrings);

   //The way things are now the tree isn't created in one go.
   //I'll have to traverse it again for the leaves.
  }

}
```

All elements of the tree share a link to the parent (for the root it's `null`). Let's create a class `TreeNode`:

```
public class TreeNode {

private TreeNode parent;
}
```

Now let's create `InnerNode` and `LeafNode` which just extends TreeNode.

```
public class InnerNode extends TreeNode {

  private BinaryTree left;
  private BinaryTree right;

  //used to set the root node
  public InnerNode() {
    super.parent = null;
    this.left=null;
    this.right=null;
  }

  public InnerNode(InnerNode parent) {
    super.parent= parent;
  }

  public TreeNode createInnerNodes(int expectedValues) {
  //recursive magic happens here. But how?
  }
}
```

and

```
public class LeafNode extends TreeNode {

  private String data;

  public LeafNode(InnerNode parent) {
    super.parent= parent;
  }

  public LeafNode createLeaves(int numOfLeaves) {
    //recursive magic happens here again. But how?
  }
}
```

### Questions and Problems

1. I want to keep the classes as separated as they are and I want to set the Tree up in one go. How to I set up `InnerNodes` and `Leaves` at the "same" time?
2. `InnerNode left` and `InnerNode right` are private so I can only access them from within `InnerNode`. But how do I deal with the leaves then? Can I just pass the root Node though to `InnerNode`/`Leaves` in a method?
3. What is best used for the recursion? Height or Number of corresponding nodes? Or something else entirely?
4. How do you set the left and right pointer? I mean the objects to which they point don't exist yet, do they?
5. Am I on the right track? /o\

Comment: I feel like having separate classes for root, inner and leaf nodes is a bit over-engineered. Since trees are recursive, it makes good sense to only have one node class. May I also ask why you're only storing data in leaves? Why do you need parent links? What is the ordering policy here? Without using all nodes in the tree for data, it seems like a waste of space and time (just use a hash, array, etc?). Your example of storing three strings shows 4 leaf nodes instead of 3. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: The tree in Example 2 is not complete ... a complete binary tree has all levels filled except maybe the last one

Comment: @ggorlen The tree is actually supposed to be a MerkleTree. So the leaves and the InnerNodes will both have hashes. If TreeNode is the superclass of the two, you can work directly with the TreeNode class and avoid duplicated code. I simpflified it to adress the recursive reation of the tree structure. I want to create the complete (but empty[no Strings in leaves yet]) binary tree (since 4 leaves for 3 strings). I would like to implement a toString() method later which traverses the tree, so you will need a parent link. Also to generate the root hash, you'll need the link to parent.

Comment: That helps clarify, thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of questions. Maybe stick to one at a time, because this will attract incomplete answers.